# Installing .NET 3.5 then service packs - how many reboots are needed?

Tags: .net

I am installing .NET 3.5 on a target server.

The Microsoft Download site is recommending I install the following:

- dotnetfx35.exe
- ndp20sp2-kb95481-x86.exe
- ndp30sp2-kb958483-x86.exe
- ndp35sp1-kb958484-x86.exe

After I run dotnetfx35.exe, it says "The system must be rebooted for the changes to take effect".

Rebooting is a big deal because there are other services running on the machine, so it will have to be a scheduled disruption.

Does anybody know - do I have to reboot before installing the service packs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with only 1 reboot if you install the 3.5 SP1 executable. That will install 3.5 and the service pack in a single install. There is a security update to 3.5 SP1 though that you should run after. So, minimum 1 reboot, maximum 2 after patch.

Link to full DotNet3.5SP1: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe

Answer (score 0):

I have previously installed multiple versions of the .NET Framework and service packs without reboots in between; however as MarkM points out, you can now do that with .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 in one package.